# Nuxt.JS (Vue.JS) and VueX binding a form to an array of objects in a VueX store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I need some help with binding a form to a list of Defaultsettings from an array of objects. I am working with NuxtJs and VueX and this is the list of Defaultsettings i have created:

- name defaultsetting (just text)
- active (a switch button that determines the defaultsetting will be active or not - boolean)
- mandatory (a radio button that determines the defaultsetting will required or not - boolean)

This is what i have so far.

With Axios i make a server side call to retrieve the list of defaultsettings and i dispatch it to the jobs store

```
        asyncData(context) {
        return context.app.$axios
            .$get('jobs/create')
            .then(data => {            
                context.store.dispatch('jobs/getDefaultsettings', data.defaultsettings)
            })
            .catch(e => context.error(e))
    },
```

In jobs.js this function gets called:

```
getDefaultsettings(context, data) {
    context.commit('setDefaultsettings', data)
},
```

getDefaultsettings then commits the data to setDefaultsettings:

```
    setDefaultsettings(state, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.mandatory = false
        d.active = false
    })
    state.defaultsettings = data
},
```

In order to have the defaultsettings in the data, i stored the state.defaultsettings in the created function.

```
        created() {
        this.ruleForm.defaultsettings =  this.$store.state.vacatures.defaultsettings

    }
```

But this is where i am confused. What is the best way to bind the data. I did found this example: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html, but i can't seem to make it work. I get the error Cannot read property 'mandatory' of undefined

```
<div class="row" v-for="defaultsetting in ruleForm.defaultsettings " :key="defaultsetting.id">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    {{defaultsetting.name}}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <el-checkbox v-model="defaultsetting.mandatory" :value="mandatory" @input="updateMandatory"/>
</div>
```

I added mandatory as a computed property:

```
        computed: {
        mandatory () { return this.$store.state.vacatures.defaultsetting.mandatory }

    },
```

And in methods:

```
 methods: {

        updateMandatory (e) {
            this.$store.commit('updateMandatory', e.target.value)
        },
    },
```

And in the jobs.js i added the mutation:

```
updateMandatory (state, setting) {
    state.defaultsetting.mandatory = setting
},
```

All the help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Been a while since I've used Vue, but comparing to https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html, it seems you're missing a ':' at mandatory <insert : here> () {}. I would also suggest using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en

Comment: Hi, thx for your comment. I am using Vue.JS, but within the framework Nuxt.JS and there : is not needed. The property does already exist, the problem that i have is with the binding to the form. 

I am already using the vue devtools

Comment: Not a real 'solution', but this package might make things easier https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields

Comment: Thx, i'm going to try it

Comment: i used the same package, so can condifrm its usefulnes for this purpose

Comment: @user2314339 Is your problem solved?

Comment: I didnt get vuex-map-fields working with Nuxt.JS, so i used a workaround. I'll add my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get vuex-map-fields to play nice with Nuxt.JS,  so i mapped the store data in created()

```
        created() {
        this.ruleForm.defaultsettings =  this.$store.state.jobs.defaultsettings.map((obj) =>  Object.assign({}, obj))

    }
```

Now when loop through this.ruleForm.defaultsettings, i can change the state using v-model

```
<div class="row" v-for="(defaultsetting, index) in ruleForm.defaultsettings " v-if="defaultsetting.groupsequence === 1"  >
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            {{defaultsetting.label}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <el-switch
                            style=""
                            v-model="ruleForm.defaultsettings[index].active"

                            active-color="#13ce66"
                            inactive-color="#ff4949"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4" v-if="ruleForm.defaultsettings[index].active === true">
                             <el-checkbox v-model="ruleForm.defaultsettings[index].mandatory"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```